# error R.java No such file or directory found

Tags: android

My project shows error in r.java.It was working fine before,all of sudden it says R.java is not found.When I tried to delete gen,gen file is generated automatically in which R.java showed error,

I tried cleaning my project,build path,deleted debug.keystore.But,of no use.

Could anyone help in resolving this issue.I am able to build new project,its all fine.The problem is only with one project

Comment: You probably have a compilation error in an XML file. Look at your console view. What does the red writing say? Anything error line with .xml on the end ding ding ding

Comment: What did you do before the errors occurred? For example did you edit 9patches or something? Usually cleaning helps but if it doesnt, there might be a slight error hiding somewhere.

Comment: It says [2011-09-01 14:33:25 - SecureDataCloud] ERROR: Unable to open class file C:\Development\QR Generator N Reader\SecureDataCloud\gen\com\orange\securedatacloud\R.java: No such file or directory.

Comment: Like Blundell said before this issue usually manifests itself when there are errors in xml or in graphical components, ie. 9patches missing lines.

Comment: Do one thing create a R.java file where it was mannually and refresh the project from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have somehow managed to fix it, but I don't know exactly what did it. Here are things I did.

- Deleted eclipse directory and reinstalled it and ADT.
- Deleted my original project that was the first to have the problem.'
- Created a new project with my original's project name.
- Manually copied all my class and res files into the new project and
  refreshed it.
- Pasted the text of the old manifest into the new manifest.

I did all this, because simply importing the original project again didn't solve anything.

After the above changes Your Project will be Fine.

Comment: You may have changed the project manifest package name without realising it. This would give you such an error. It would also be resolved by this method as the manifest would have been regenerated and you wouldn't have copied this over.

Comment: But even I checked manifest ,package name is same in both r.java and manifest

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem. simply i delete my r.java file and restart eclipse then this problem is solved.